# String to datetime conversion "M/dd/yyyy"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a date string `4/30/2016`

I tried to convert it by using  following code:

`DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date);`

and I am getting the error

> The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.

Can you please help me How can I solve this issue?
and why this error is happening?

Answer (score 9):

There is a `DateTime.ParseExact` method for such a tasks. You can provide it with expected date format.

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var format = "M/dd/yyyy";
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider)
```

Comment: I prefer `TryParseExact`

Comment: I have tried with following code                                     DateTime.TryParseExact(beginDate, "M/dd/yyyy",  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out startdate);   and i am getting the output value as {01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM}. But the input was "4/30/2016"

Comment: try editing your original question with the code you are using, what you put down should work.             DateTime startdate;
            DateTime.TryParseExact("4/30/2016"
                , "M/d/yyyy"
                , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                , DateTimeStyles.None
                , out startdate);. Worked for me